# Available + used size only 19% of total partition size

Tags: partitioning, disk, df

I have a VPS with Ubuntu on OpenVZ.
I noticed a day ago that the output of the df -h command returns strange values.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       54G  1.5G  8.8G  14% /
devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G  3.6M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  9.2M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
```

You can see that the total of available and used on /dev/simfs partition is 10.3GB, while the whole partition should be 54GB big.

I searched online but can't find anything useful. People usually have problems with open deleted files, but I doubt that this is a problem here.

Do you guys have any idea what might be causing this strange issue? Is this something my VPS provider has to fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance.  Favour returned: Question upvoted!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between **thick and thin provisioning:**

- **Thick provisioning**: The full disk space you request is allocated and reserved for you and for you only. (expensive!)
- **Thin provisioning:** The disk space your request is shared with other users and only the disk space you actually use is allocated to you and the free space is allocated from a shared pool. (cheap and how most CSPs do things nowadays)

As I don't work at OpenVZ, I don't know how they physically allocate your space, but if they use best practices you'll see the Avail column grow if you get between 50% and 85% of actual usage up to your maximum of 54G.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just created a few large files, so my disk usage is now 93% of my "available" space. I will see if it expands as you said ;)

Comment: Keep me informed...

Comment: Your predictions were correct :) My available space automatically extended, even though it took the server 12 hours to detect that I am running out of space.
Here is the new summary for the "/" partition.
`/dev/simfs       60G  4.5G   16G  22% /`
Keep in mind that I purchased the package with 60GB of space, so the Size was also increased to 60GB :)

Comment: [I love it when a plan comes together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_%22Hannibal%22_Smith)  **;-)**